# How do I fix the error saying there's an unknown field even though I have it in my database?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So as I was running this program, I got this error saying that "ShopperID" is an unknown field although it's indicated in my database in MS Access. It also inserts all the inputs done before that error occurs.

The error I got:

'The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'ShopperID'.  Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.'

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class acer
    Private Sub acer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Stocks from vbProduct where ProdID = @pID ", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "P-1001"
        conn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCart.Click

        Dim sdate As DateTime = Today
        Dim shipdate As DateTime
        shipdate = sdate.AddDays(5)
        shipdate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
        sdate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into vbCart(DateTime_Created,DateTime_Checkout,Delivery_Date,ProdID,Cart_ItemsQty,Cart_Items,ShopperID)values
(@created, @checkout, @ship, @pID,@quanti,@items,@UID) ", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = sdate
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkout", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = sdate
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ship", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = shipdate
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "P-1001"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quanti", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nudqty.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@items", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "ACER NITRO 5"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = String.Format("{0}{1}, ", sformat, sID)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        TeamAudit("ADD TO CART, ACER NITRO 5, " + String.Format("{0}{1}, ", sformat, sID) + sLast + ", " + sFirst)
        conn.Close()
        Me.Hide()
        example.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I alrerady tried changing its values

Comment: Can you add a screen-grab of your database configuration, please?
Without it, we are just guessing as to what might be wrong.

Comment: Neither `sID` nor `sformat` seems to hold a value. Also, the dates are inserted as _text_. Always store and pass date and time as true _DateTime_ values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fields in the "INSERT INTO" are in EXACTLY the same order as the fields in the Access database.  I think that is why JayV asked for a screen-grab of the database. This has bit me a few times...Good luck!